# jquery send blob to audio tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created from a base64 a blob and would now like to send this via jquery to my  to say more exactly to the src =.
There is however always unknown ... when I copy the blob url from the console and copy by hand purely it works!
I do not understand where my mistake is ...

```
<div class="col-xs-5 ">
                            <div class="col-xs-1 ">
                            <div class="brown-bg2" id="rahmen2">
                            <i class="fa fa-microphone fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" id="beer"></i>


                                <script>

                                    var b64 = "@location1.getAudio";


                                    function base64toBlob(base64Data) {

                                        var byteString = atob(base64Data);
                                        var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
                                        var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);

                                        for(var i=0; i< byteString.length;i++){
                                            ia[i]=byteString.charCodeAt(i);
                                        }
                                        return new Blob([ab],{type: 'audio/wav'});
                                    }

                                    var blob = base64toBlob(b64);
                                    var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);


                                    console.log(blobUrl);


                                    $("resposivaudio").attr("src",blobUrl);

                                </script>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 ">
                            <audio id="resposivaudio" controls="controls"  src="" >
                            </audio>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--/.info-box-->
```

Comment: You're executing the script before the `<audio>` tag exists, try moving that script block to after the `<audio>` tag.

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work unfortunately

Comment: Oh, heh, you're missing a # at the beginning of your jquery selector for the audio tag, should be `$("#resposivaudio").attr("src",blobUrl);`

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution! That I myself is not noticed = D

Comment: Dude your code pointed me to the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Do  not know much but if you call to somewhere outside, it may not have the answer ready when your code needs to execute. Try send it as asyncrone call.. Maybe it helps?

Comment: Hmm ... I do not quite exactly how I should implement your proposal ...
I have my script now already in its own .js packed but as always still unknown. Could you explain this to me more precisely?